# Parents Order By Query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

My table look like this:

```
id auto increment
pid (for parents id)
page_cat_subcat (0 for category 1 for subcategory and 2 for topic)
title (page title)
position (position for category, subcategory and topic)
```

This is my table.....

PHP & CSS are category
Loop & Function are subcategory of PHP
CSS 3 & CSS 1 are subcategory of CSS
and rest are topics....

I want to ouput like this

CSS
  **CSS3**
    Border
  **CSS1**
    Background

PHP
  **Loop**
    For Loop
    Foreach Loop
    While Loop
  **Function**
    Parameter
    Argument

I tried this

```
SELECT id, pid, title
FROM test
ORDER BY case when pid=0 then id else pid end * 1000 + id ASC
```

But Result Look Like This

PHP
 Loop
 Function

CSS
 CSS3
 CSS1

For Loop
Foreach Loop
While Loop
Border
Parameter
Argument
Background

Comment: Can you format your actual & desired o/p?

Comment: I already mention above how i want ouput from my query

Comment: can you show some sample data?

Comment: Here is image of my table http://postimg.org/image/6iflejzbr/

Comment: Check this post : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161

Comment: Hi, its very advance for me.... I can not understand the code....

Comment: U are doing something similar so it will be helpful for you if you go through that post.